# IoS 7 blurry coretext on CALayer

Tags: ios, ios7

I have problem with Core Text when it's rendered to CALayer the text is blurry. I did check the position to be integral and frame height and width but still text appears blurry. The layout is simple in the IB i have standard UIView, then in the code i will create CALayer, append this layer to UIView layer and will draw text to this layer with :

drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context{

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(lroundf(self.view.frame.size.width/2), lroundf(self.view.frame.size.height/2))];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    CALayer *newLayer = [[CALayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.view.layer];
    newLayer.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    newLayer.delegate=self;
    [self.view.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(lroundf(self.view.frame.size.width/2), lroundf(self.view.frame.size.height/2))];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:newLayer];
    [newLayer setNeedsDisplay];

}


-(void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)currentContext{
   NSLog(@"drawLayer Layer position x %f pos y %f", layer.position.x,layer.position.y);
   NSLog(@"drawLayer Layer origin x %f y %f", layer.bounds.origin.x,layer.bounds.origin.y);
   NSLog(@"drawLayer Layer bounds width %f height %f", layer.bounds.size.width,layer.bounds.size.height);

    layer.contentsScale=[[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
    CTFontRef fontRef =
    CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Didot", 36, NULL);
    NSDictionary *attrDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: (__bridge id)fontRef, (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (NSString *)(kCTForegroundColorAttributeName), nil];
    CFRelease(fontRef); 

    // Flip the coordinate system
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    NSAttributedString *timeMarker = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello blurry text !!!" attributes:attrDictionary] ;
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)timeMarker);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(currentContext, 0, 50);
    CTLineDraw(line, currentContext);
    CFRelease(line);
}
```

Here is the View bounds:

```
DrawRect[14767:15435976] View bounds <UIView: 0x7fe153d22980; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe153d21c40>>

Below is NSLOG:
2014-11-25 20:18:10.159 DrawRect[15103:15454664] viewDidLoad View Position x 187.500000 pos y 333.500000 
2014-11-25 20:18:10.159 DrawRect[15103:15454664] viewDidLoad View bounds width 375.000000 heights 667.000000
2014-11-25 20:18:10.159 DrawRect[15103:15454664] viewDidLoad View bounds origin x 0.000000 x 0.000000

2014-11-25 20:18:10.159 DrawRect[15103:15454664] viewDidLoad View frame size width 375.000000 height 667.000000
2014-11-25 20:18:10.159 DrawRect[15103:15454664] viewDidLoad View frame origin width 0.000000 height 0.000000

2014-11-25 20:18:10.160 DrawRect[15103:15454664] View Layer frame size width 375.000000 height 667.000000
2014-11-25 20:18:10.160 DrawRect[15103:15454664] View Layer origin width 0.000000 height 0.000000

2014-11-25 20:18:10.165 DrawRect[15103:15454664] drawLayer Layer position x 188.000000 pos y 334.000000
2014-11-25 20:18:10.165 DrawRect[15103:15454664] drawLayer Layer origin x 0.000000 y 0.000000
2014-11-25 20:18:10.165 DrawRect[15103:15454664] drawLayer Layer bounds width 375.000000 height 667.000000

2014-11-25 20:18:10.166 DrawRect[15103:15454664] drawLayer after CTM Layer position x 188.000000 pos y 334.000000
2014-11-25 20:18:10.166 DrawRect[15103:15454664] drawLayer after CTM Layer origin x 0.000000 y 0.000000
2014-11-25 20:18:10.174 DrawRect[15103:15454664] drawLayer after CTM Layer bounds width 375.000000 height 667.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue was printing CALayer object (po 0x7fec22927c40) in the debugger.

CABackingStore buffer had same values as layer bounds [375 853], but based on the scale definition CAlayer should draw twice in the buffer.

Infer was that second draw was skipped. My layer.contentsScale was in the method:

```
drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)currentContext
```

When layer.contentsScale was moved to the viewDidLoad method problem was fixed.

```
CALayer *newLayer = [[CALayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.view.layer];
    newLayer.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    newLayer.delegate=self;
    newLayer.contentsScale=2;
```

CABackingStore buffer from [375 853] become [750 1706].

The text was crisp even with non integral super view position.

```
viewDidLoad View Position x 187.500000 pos y 333.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the problem right there on the first line of your log output:

> ```
> 2014-11-25 20:18:10.159 DrawRect[15103:15454664] 
>         viewDidLoad View Position x 187.500000 pos y 333.500000
> ```

You've positioned your layer on a half-pixel. It's impossible for half a pixel to light up, so you're getting multiple pixels with anti-aliasing. That's the "blur".

> I did check the position to be integral

Well, all I can say about that is, no you didn't. Your logging proves it. Try to get your coordinates *integral* and *even* — integral so that they are not on half-pixels, and even so that the center is not on a half-pixel.

Comment: Thanks matt for pointing this out. I corrected the values but still get same thing. I did check the center point, width and height. Maybe i'm missing again something that is obvious, but i can't figure this out. Could you please try the above code in the default(xcode6) project setup and point me where the problem lies. Appreciate if you would have time to help me with this.